# Venn Diagram Automation tool

Tags: r, venn-diagrams

I would like to ask if there is a solution in any language that can help me create and maintain a venn diagram similar to the one below that I can insert in my latex text.

I have already found some solutions in R but it seems that they cannot build diagrams similar to the one below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you could use Tikz to do this. But im not sure what you mean with automated.

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Here is an example of a Venn diagram made with Tikz http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

This is the manual  http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf

Comment: This isn't really an answer, is it? More a comment. The example linked is really nothing at all like the one in the question....

Comment: @cfr he asked for a way to create and maintain a Venn diagram. AFAIK you can do so using tikz. Or am I supposed to make it for him?

Comment: Indeed, I'm sure you can. But that's why this is more of a comment than an answer. It is basically just giving the name of a package. As I say, I don't see that example being much help with this diagram. Indeed, I don't think TiKZ is a good solution here at all. Not if the idea is to create something which can be automated.

Comment: That's true. I don't really understand what he means with automated. What exactly he wants automated.

Comment: Yes. The question is not at all clear....